# How did this main Harry Potter character die?

Tags: harry-potter

I might be missing something obvious but when I read the seventh Harry Potter, it wasn't clear to me how Voldemort died. How did Voldemort die?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

He (Voldemort) was dueling with the elder wand, which was loyal (at this point) to Harry, due to a circuitous chain that has been discussed in other threads.  When they both cast at the same time, his spell rebounded upon him.  Why this should be the case is open to speculation (and there has been a lot), but it's pretty clearly laid out in the text of the book:

> Tom Riddle hit the floor with a mundane finality, his body feeble and shrunken, the white hands empty, the snakelike face vacant and unknowing. Voldemort was dead, **killed by his own rebounding curse**, and Harry stood with two wands in his hand, staring down at his enemy’s shell.

[Emphasis added]

Comment: Oh. Thank you for pointing that out. I'd always thought that he was killed by remorse.   ** “It’s your one last chance,” said Harry, “it’s all you’ve got left. . . .I’ve seen what you’ll be otherwise. . . . Be a man . . . try . . . Try for some remorse. . . .”**

Comment: @EmilyCampbell - Actually, Remorse was the one thing that could have 'saved' him to some degree or another; Hermione explains that when she is talking about how a Horcrux is created; basically, it could be unmade, and the soul recombined.. but only by the caster feeling remorse for what they did in creating it, and the level of remorse they would suffer could well kill them.  But it was still an (albeit painful) option for redemption/salvation that Harry was pointing out to an unheeding Voldemort.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, since Neville killed Nagini, Voldemorts last existing Horcrux, Voldemort lost concentration on fighting back Harry's spell and resulting in the Killing Curse rebounding on him, killing him. Let's say Neville didn't get to Nagini, then the curse may not have even rebounded. If it did, Voldemort would not have been killed.

Comment: I think the (main at least) reason for the curse to rebound is the loyalty of the Elder Wand (as in the answer above). Do you have any evidence to support your theory?