# How could Harry kill Voldemort by a disarming charm?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Harry finally kills Voldemort. But manages it by striking Voldemort with the disarming charm **Expelliarmus**.

How is it possible? I mean you can't obviously kill someone with a disarming charm.

Comment: because Voldemort was finally tired of *vol*-ing from *de* *mort*. :p

Comment: @Shreedhar I think you didn't make yourself clear enough.

Comment: @AsifIqubal i was jk man. it was just a wise play at his name. Vol-de-mort in French vaguely translates to flight/running from death. On a serious note, you do have the answer in the link provided above by KitKat.

Comment: @Kitkat Why did the curse rebound?

Comment: @AsifIqubal see also the answers to [How could Expelliarmus beat Avada Kedavra?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/how-could-expelliarmus-beat-avada-kedavra)